# How make bash loop over muiti-word directory names to move directories?

Tags: bash, mv

Directory `src` has two subdirectories: `this that` and `here & now`. What bash script (under macOS) will move both those subdirectories into directory `target`?

I tried the following, with and without the escaping of embedded spaces and of the "&", but neither works:

```
#! /bin/bash

dirArray=("this that" "here\ \& now")
for val in "${dirArray[@]}"
do
    mv $val ~/Desktop/HoldMath/
done
```

Comment: Quote the variable `$val`.

Comment: You don't need to escape space and `&` inside quotes.

Comment: @Barmar: perfect! thank you.